# MVC dropdown list readonly doesn't work

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html-select

Below is the code where the dropdownlist is generated (in View)

```
@Html.DropDownList("feeTypes", null, new { @disabled = false })
```

The above line works fine when I change false to true, but when I set to false, it's also disabled (i.e. the dropdownlist is always disabled whenever I put true or false)

Why the above situation happens?

What I actually want to do is to make a dropdownlist which can be enabled or disabled programmably, are there any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The disabled property will disable if present at all, regardless of the value. You end up having a conditional in razor because of this:

```
@if(disabled){
    Html.DropDownList("feeTypes", null, new { @disabled = false })
}
else{
    Html.DropDownList("feeTypes", null)
}
```

Comment: There was at the time, and a downvote should accompany an explanation, since this answer is correct.

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT:**

You can set disabled to null (or maybe an empty string), then that attribute wont be rendered.

```
@Html.DropDownList("feeTypes", null, cond ? new { @disabled = "" } : null)
```

where `cond` is either true or false

*The discussion below started with an erronous version. It has been fixed and tested now!*

Comment: @user2191496: What razor version are you on?

Comment: How to check the razor version..?

Comment: @user2191496: I believe MVC3 uses 1.0 and MVC4 uses 2.0

Comment: @user2191496: You're right. It doesnt. My bad (Didn't test the code...)

Answer (score 2):

You need it to be:

```
@Html.DropDownList("feeTypes", null, new { @disabled = "disabled" })
```

If you want the dropdown to be enabled, you dont want the `disabled` attribute in there at all, put:

```
@Html.DropDownList("feeTypes", null)
```

If you want to be able to toggle between the 2 consider using some JavaScript/jQuery

Comment: Problem solved, you're downvoted maybe because the @disabled should be set to false instead of a string (I didn't downvoted your answer)

Comment: It doesn't matter what `@disabled` is set to, the fact that it is there is all that matters. If it did matter then setting `@disabled=false` would achieve the opposite to what you want. Having `@disabled=true/false/enabled/disabled/""/banana/anything` doesn't matter, this will cause the dropdown to be disabled. However the only way to enable the dropdown is to remove the `@disabled` attribute altogether

Answer (score 2):

"disabled = false" is kind of redundant.  In the resulting markup, for an element to *not* be disabled then you don't want the `disabled` attribute on it at all.  For example:

A disabled element:

```
@Html.DropDownList("feeTypes", null, new { @disabled = true })
```

A not-disabled element:

```
@Html.DropDownList("feeTypes")
```

There's no HTML markup to specify "this is not disabled."  Rather, elements are not disabled by default until you specify the `disabled` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Disabled attribute it doesn't really need any parameters to be activated. Only by mentioning disabled (without any parameters) it disable the DOM element

```
<input type="text" disabled />
```

Since non parameter attributes are not validated we usually add a parameter to be xhtml valid

```
<input type="text" disabled="ItDoesntReallyMatter" />
```

The thing you have to do is remove the attribute completely from the element using jquery or simple javascript.

```
document.getElementsByTagName("feeTypes")[0].removeAttribute("disabled ");
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `disabled` attribute if you want  to re-enable it. There is no such thing as `disabled="enabled"`. Even markup like `<input type="text" disabled />` will disable your input in modern browsers.

See [the html5 reference](http://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/#empty-attr) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

After putting readonly on your dropdownlist, put this inside style tag..

```
<style>
 select[readonly] option, select[readonly] optgroup {
        display: none;
    }
<style>
```